# Find pair of tangents to circle

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

> Find pair of tangents from $(3,4)$ to circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=9$

We have to find tangents to circle.
I have supposed a line $$y = mx  + c.$$
By condition of tangency I have $$c = 3\sqrt{1+m^{2}}.$$
Now as this line passes through $(3,4)$
I have

$$4 = 3m + 3\sqrt{1+m^{2}}.$$

$$ \therefore\quad 4-3m = 3\sqrt{1+m^{2}}$$

Squaring on both sides 
$$\therefore\quad 16 +9m^{2} -24m = 9 + 9m^{2}$$

$$\therefore\quad 7 -24m = 0$$

now I am stuck here
as $(3,4)$ is *outside*  *the*  *Circle* , there must be *two* tangents from $(3,4)$ but here $m$ only has one value. Now what to do?

Comment: $$c=\pm3\sqrt{1+m^2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tangent at x=3 is parallel to y-axis at distance3, with a distance from given point to circle center as 5. Since it has $ m = \infty$ it will not show up in your calculation which assumed $m$ to be non-infinite. I.e., $ m,c $ both go to $\infty$. Other tangent slope $\frac{7}{24}$ ok.